# How to create a table type in Sql Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm trying to create a table type in sql server 2005.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
    CREATE TYPE NameResourceType AS TABLE
(
   ID int, 
   [Value] Varchar(256) 
)
GO
```

I receive the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Table alias data types & Table-Valued parameters were introduced in SQL Server 2008 so are not available in prior versions.

Answer (score 4):

[New in SQL Server 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/whats-new.aspx)... "Table-Valued Parameters"

[CREATE TYPE in SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007%28SQL.90%29.aspx) refers to "simple" user defined data types only... notice the difference in the [SQL Server 2008 CREATE TYPE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007.aspx)