# SQL server 2005 How to create user defined table type

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

i create table type and create stored procedure take table type as aparameter this code working in sql server 2008

```
CREATE TYPE [MyDataTable] AS TABLE(
    [EmpID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EmpName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [EmpSal] [money] NULL,
    [EmpAddress] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [EmpDeptID] [int] NULL
    )
```

can i do thing like this code in sql server 2005

Comment: No. They were a new feature with 2008. Compare [`CREATE TYPE` (2005)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007(v=sql.90).aspx) and [`CREATE TYPE` (2008)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007(v=sql.100).aspx)

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606263/how-to-create-a-table-type-in-sql-server-2005